# Looping through array and grouping data based on a criteria in perl

Tags: arrays, perl, loops, conditional-statements, grouping

I have an array as mentioned below with four columns. Each column represents start, end position, DNA strand, and genes respectively. I want to categorize each rows into number of groups as mentioned below.

Criteria: When the difference between end position of one row and start position of next rows is less than 55 then it will be grouped in one list.

```
410 1750 + dnaA     
1939 3075 + dnaB     
3206 3421 + daaR    
3437 4549 + becG     
4567 4812 + yaaB  
4860 6783 + vyrY   
15915 17381 + guaB   
19062 19946 + UsaD  
19968 20558 + byaE

output format:

List 1:  
410 1750 + dnaA

List 2:  
1939 3075 + dnaN

List 3:  
3206 3421 + yaaA  
3437 4549 + recF  
4567 4812 + yaaB  
4860 6783 + gyrB

List 4:   
15915 17381 + guaB

List 5:   
19062 19946 + yaaD   
19968 20558 + yaaE
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site where experienced programmers can ask their peers for help with a problem that has them beaten. It isn't an opportunity for the world to get software engineering done for free. Would you consider offering your skills as a biologist for nothing? Do you think of Software Engineer as a *real job*?

Comment: Mr.Borodin I am a undergrad student, who is working on cancer data to find significant genes for my project. I never taken programming courses before and I could'nt afford to pay a software engineer to do this. I am just asking for help. I chose biology to serve the community once I become a biologist through my research not just for money. Kindly help me if possible.Thanks

Comment: @fugu I read it as "grad" student ... *sigh* Either way, without code, this question should be closed for now.

Comment: @Angie I wonder if you'll not take a paycheck from the pharmaceutical company that conducts the research you intend to do after graduation, and whether they'll give the resulting medicine away for free. All in the name of helping out, right? Our sense of fulfillment will keep our stomach's full!

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You can use the following as a start.

I assumed, the data parts are split by single spaces, as given in your example and that data is in a file called "data.txt".

The result is an array of arrays that contain the elements that are to be grouped together.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#

use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

open(my $fd, "<", "data.txt")
    || die("could not open file: $!");


my @sets;

my %last;
my $set_index = 0;

while (<$fd>) {

    my %current;

    ($current{start}, $current{end}, undef, $current{sequence}) = split(" ", $_);
  if(exists($last{end}) &&
       $current{start} - $last{end} >= 55) {
        push(@sets, []);
        $set_index++;
    }
    push(@{$sets[$set_index]}, \%current);

    %last = %current;
}

print Dumper(@sets);
```

Besides knowing arrays and hashes you also need to understand how complex data structures are built with perl using references. This is explained in http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html and there is an indepth introduction in http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html.

This is definitely not the most succinct way of achieving what you want, but I hope, it is understandable.

Nevertheless you won't have much joy using it, if you don't try to understand what is happening as you will need to make changes of your own.

Comment: Feel free to formulate a new question if you want your code to be corrected.